# Neo4j reverse lookup - get index from node via cypher query

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, reverse-lookup

We can search a node by index via cypher query:

`START n=node:index('property:val') RETURN n;`

Is there a possible reverse query which we can get the index from a node id?

So if a node is retrieved via node id, how can we retrieve all indices of the particular node as well?

Comment: not possible sorry, what is your use-case?

Comment: @Micheal - I'd like to create a dynamic function that I can reuse which will check a relationship between two nodes by node ids.  I'd like to perform the check with indices for performance... I guess I can do the same by just node id now that I think about it.